# JGit - Pushing a branch and add upstream (-u option)

Tags: java, jgit

In `JGit`, I search a way to push a branch and add the upstream reference (tracking).

It is the option `-u` or `--set-upstream` into the [push command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html).

I don't see a method in the class `PushCommand` which permits to do this.

Please, could you tell me how I can do this ?

```
PushCommand pushCommand = git.push()
                    .setRemote(remoteAlias)
                    .setRefSpecs(spec);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JGit `PushCommand` does not offer this functionality (yet), but you can modify the repository configuration like `--set-upstream` would.

If you pass a remote alias to `setRemote()` (like the snippet from the question suggests), you need to set the upstream like so:

```
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.setString(CONFIG_BRANCH_SECTION, "local-branch", "remote", "remote-alias-name");
config.setString(CONFIG_BRANCH_SECTION, "local-branch", "merge", "refs/heads/name-of-branch-on-remote");
config.save();
```

This will result in this configuration section

```
[branch "local-branch"] 
remote = remote-alias-name 
merge = refs/heads/name-of-branch-on-remote
```

If the remote hasn't been configured yet (i.e. there is no section `[remote "remote-alias-name"]`, you will also have to create such a section. For example, like this:

```
config.setString(CONFIG_REMOTE_SECTION, "remote-alias-name", "url", "url-of-remote");
config.setString(CONFIG_REMOTE_SECTION, "remote-alias-name", "fetch", "ref-spec");
```

Constants are defined in class `ConfigConstants`.

Comment: It works fine, thanks. I can now do a fetch without specified the remote branch. But I don't understand why I doesn't have the information of the tracked branch when I do a git branch -vv. Do you know why ? Maybe it is because the tracked information is stored into the gitconfig file.

Comment: If you create a branch with the `CreateBranchCommand` and the start point dentes a branch you can specify whether the new branch should track the start point through `setUpstreamMode()`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It is finally OK, it was my fault ! When I have configured my remote I forgot to called remoteConfig.addFetchRefSpec, that's why when I called git branch -vv, it didin't show me the tracked branch... Thanks for your answer that was perfect.